# Setting HttpServletRequest as a testing method argument using MvcMock

Tags: spring-mvc, junit4, mockmvc

I am in process of writing a junit for one of the controller methods with method signature as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getTokenizedURL.json",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseData getTokenizedURL(@RequestBody final RequestData requestData, final HttpServletRequest request) throws CustomException
```

I need to call this method using MockMvc and I am able to call using below:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/user/getTokenizedURL.json")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content(json))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

But the problem is I am unable to setup `HttpServletRequest` Parameter while calling the original method using mock mvc. Without setting `HttpServletRequest` argument, my test is giving issues since it is something required and used with in original method.

Please let me know how should I setup the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that you shouldn't need to.

[`MockMvcRequestBuilders#post(..)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#post-java.net.URI-) returns a [`MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html) which lets you construct the request with any values you want. These will be mirrored in the `HttpServletRequest` that gets passed to your handler method.

For example, you used

```
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

this will set the `content-type` header of the request. In your handler method, if you did

```
request.getHeader("content-type");
```

you'd get back a corresponding `String` for the `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`.

The `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder` has "setters" for every part of the request.

Comment: Ohh yes.. Got it. I wanted to add attribute in session inside request which I am able do using below:

MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
session.setAttribute("username", "kb@test.com");
        
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockBuilder = post("/user/getTokenizedURL.json").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json).session(session).servletPath("/user/getTokenizedURL.json");

mockMvc.perform(mockBuilder).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());

Many Thanks Sotirios!!!